# How can I delete rows from two tables?

Tags: sql

I have `table1` and `table2`. I need to delete from table1 all rows. When I try `DELETE FROM table1` this error appear

> 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (db_name.table2, CONSTRAINT table2_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY
>   (table1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id))

How can I delete all rows in table1, and all rows in table2, which `table1_id` match with `id` from `table1`?

Comment: You are not allowed to delete those table_1 rows because they have dependent rows in table2. Do first delete from table_2, then you can delete from table_1.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id
);
DELETE FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates an issue where there is a foreign key reference from `table2` to `table1`. To solve this you have a few options:

- Delete the records referring to the `table1` record from `table2`, before deleting the record in `table1`
- Add a `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Start by deleting table2 then table1

or add before deleting :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

then after deletion completed :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```